# Enabling URL rewriting for API

Tags: apache, php, webserver, api

I'm new to configuring API web servers and I'm trying to enable URL rewriting for the server so that a user can go to *my public DNS*.com/getAlbum to access a method within my api.php file (assumption, I'm still learning this all). I was given the command `cd /etc/apache2/mods-enabled; ln -s ../mods/rewrite.load rewrite.load`, however when I run that, it says it fails to create the symbolic link "rewrite.load": File exists. I checked this file and it contains the same code located in **mods-available**/rewrite.load, so I think there is something incorrect in apache2.conf. I can also update this to include any needed info. How do enable URL rewriting to get my API working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the easier way to enable a modules is with `a2enmod` So you could do `a2enmod rewrite`.

But that 'file exists' error you're getting probably means its already enabled. Make sure to do an `apache2ctl graceful` to activate the new config.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @derobert, running your command `apache2ctl graceful` returns the following..
`httpd not running, trying to start
(13)Permission denied: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
(13)Permission denied: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
no listening sockets available, shutting down
AH00015: Unable to open logs
Action 'graceful' failed.`

Comment: @exeleon need to run it as root. Or with sudo in front of it.

Comment: Thanks it worked however I cannot access methods within api.php by going to `http://my public dns.com/methodname`, though I can access other files normally via the browser. could it be something incorrectly set in htaccess or apache2.conf?

Comment: @exeleon quite possibly. Your rewrite rules might be wrong, your vhost set up wrong, etc. Now that you've got the rewrite module enabled, you can ask questions about those... I'm not sure if here is the best place or if [webmasters.se] wants rewrite questions.

Comment: Thanks for all of your help @derobert! I'll head over there-